# Cannot access web server inside ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am learning AWS and is trying to setup a web server on ec2, but I can't access the web server from outside even after I tried everything I can think of.

Here is the cloudformation template I am using:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  ## VPC
  # Create a VPC
  HelloVpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsHostnames: "true"
      EnableDnsSupport: "true"
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: HelloVpc
  # Create internet gateway for public subnet
  HelloInternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: HelloInternetGateway
  HelloVPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: HelloVpc
      InternetGatewayId:
        Ref: HelloInternetGateway
  # Create route table for public subnet
  HelloPublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: HelloPublicRouteTable
      VpcId:
        Ref: HelloVpc
  HelloInternetGatewayRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId:
        Ref: HelloPublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId:
        Ref: HelloInternetGateway
  # create subnets
  HelloVpcPrivateSubNet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: HelloVpc
      AvailabilityZone: { "Fn::Select": [0, { "Fn::GetAZs": "" }] }
      CidrBlock: 10.0.2.0/24
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: HelloVpcPrivateSubNet
  HelloVpcPublicSubNet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: HelloVpc
      AvailabilityZone: { "Fn::Select": [1, { "Fn::GetAZs": "" }] }
      CidrBlock: 10.0.1.0/24
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: HelloVpcPublicSubNet
  HelloPublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId:
        Ref: HelloPublicRouteTable
      SubnetId:
        Ref: HelloVpcPublicSubNet
  ## Security group
  HelloSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow http and ssh
      VpcId:
        Ref: HelloVpc
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 5000
          ToPort: 5000
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 5000
          ToPort: 5000
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  ## EC2
  HelloEc2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0c91eefc31e3b0867
      InstanceType: t3.nano
      KeyName: EC2-KP
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
          DeviceIndex: "0"
          SubnetId:
            Ref: HelloVpcPublicSubNet
          GroupSet:
            - Ref: HelloSecurityGroup
```

Then I SSH into the instance and started a web server with

```
mkdir app
cd app
dotnet new web
dotnet run
```

which starts a web server on port 5000 and `curl http://localhost:5000` works fine.

Since I can ssh into the instance, the ACL and security group should be correct. I googled around and tried to disable the firewall with

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -F
```

but it still doesn't work.

At this point, I really have no idea what goes wrong. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I'd assume that it's listening on localhost only. Re-run it with 0.0.0.0 to override the default localhost. Not sure this is correct for dotnet but maybe: `--urls http://0.0.0.0:5000`

Comment: What are your ACLs? Why do you modify default ones?

Comment: @jarmod Thanks a lot! never realized `dotnet run` only listen on localhost only.

Comment: @Marcin I just use the default ACLs without any modification. The problem isn't the ACL. Thanks anyway

Comment: @jarmod sure, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `dotnet run` causes your app to listen on localhost, so it's only reachable locally within the server itself.

You need it to bind to the public IP of the server, which you can do as follows:

```
dotnet run --urls http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

For additional options to set the URL, see [here](https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/).